# NSArray remove last object of type?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, subviews

Working with an array of UIViews and UIImageViews ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] window] subviews]). I need to remove only the object of the highest index of the UIImageView type.

Comment: NOTE: You need to use an NSMutableArray instead of a NSArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

another block-based solution

```
[window.subviews enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse 
                                  usingBlock:^(id view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            *stop=YES;
    }
}];
```

non-block solution:

```
for (UIView *view in [window.subview reverseObjectEnumerator])
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            break;
    }
}
```

I published [some demo code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/TestSubviewsRemove), that shows both solutions.

Comment: These could be improved by removing the view directly inside the loop, then you wouldn't need the viewToRemove variable any more.

Comment: are you sure? in fast enumeration it is forbidden to alter the array while enumerating.

Comment: @NickLockwood For the reverseObjectEnumerator you are right. but not, if you fast enumerate over the array directly.

Comment: Yeah, true. I forgot you can't safely modify an array while iterating over it.

Comment: @Kyle I confirmed it myself. see my edit for even prettier code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `indexOfObjectWithOptions:passingTest:` method to search the array in reverse for an object that passes a test using a block, and then delete the object at the resulting position:

```
NSUInteger pos = [myArray indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse
                          passingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]; // <<== EDIT (Thanks, Nick Lockwood!)
}];
if (pos != NSNotFound) {
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:pos];
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but you should compare the type using isKindOfClass instead of ==, otherwise if the UIImageView is actually a subclass of UIImageView it won't work.

Comment: @NickLockwood That's a nice catch, thank you very much for spotting the problem!

Comment: You also need to add a check that pos != NSNotFound, or it will crash if the array doesn't contain a UIImageView.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] window];
UIView *imageView = nil;
for (UIView *view in window.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        imageView = view;
    }
}

//this will be the last imageView we found
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Well Kyle liked your solution better anyway, so i guess you win, lol ;-)

Comment: :) My code usually spends 30 min in front of the mirror every day, to become pretty.

Comment: See my comment above - you can improve it even further.

Comment: I bow to your dedication to the pursuit of perfection! +1s all round.

Comment: I am sick at home. I try to eliminate some time.

Comment: I preferred vikingosegundo's solution because it enumerated from the last element to the first. Since I only expect there to be a single other view on the stack following the last UIImageView it might be marginally faster. Your solution was the first one that worked, and had no errors/edits.